# @Namespace in Android SimpleXml

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I have this file XML:

```
<Name  xml:lang="en">English</Name> <Name  xml:lang="it">Italian</Name>
```

And my class :

```
@Element
@Namespace(reference = "en", prefix = "lang")
public class Name {

    @Text
    private String title;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title.toUpperCase() + "\n";
}
```

Why when i do toString, it do not print only name in English?

Tnks

Answer (score 5):

There are some things wrong in your class:

1. You have to use `@Root` for classes, not `@Element`
2. Your `@Namespace` is set for the class, not the attribute
3. Because of 2. you don't get an attribute
4. Is the reference of your namespace correct?
5. Your xml is a *list*, not a single class

If you serialize your class to xml, you will get something like this:

```
<lang:name xmlns:lang="en">Example</lang:name>
```

--> Not matching your input.

---

Here's a corrected version:

```
@Root(name = "Name")
public class Name
{
    @Text()
    private String text;
    @Attribute(name = "lang")
    @Namespace(prefix = "xml", reference = "") // Add your reference here!
    private String attr;


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return text.toUpperCase() + "\n";
    }
}
```

This serializes to:

```
<name xml:lang="en" xmlns:xml="">English</name>
```

Please note, there's no *reference* set yet - but you can ignore it's attribute.

Now you'll get a single `Name` into an object. However, your xml contains a list of those. Therefore you need another class mapping this list:

```
@Root(name = "Names")
public class NameList
{
    @ElementList(name = "Names", inline = true)
    private List<Name> names;
}
```

For testing you can serialize this too:

```
<Names>
   <Name xml:lang="en" xmlns:xml="">English</Name>
   <Name xml:lang="it" xmlns:xml="">Italian</Name>
</Names>
```

Please note those tags around.

This is pretty close to your input; remember: `xmlns:xml` - the reference - can be ignored. So just correct your xml. Assuming you have a parent-element `Names`:

```
<Names>
    <Name xml:lang=\"en\">English</Name>
    <Name xml:lang=\"it\">Italian</Name>
</Names>
```

And the final test now:

```
final String xml = "<Names>"
                 +   "<Name xml:lang=\"en\">English</Name>"
                 +   "<Name xml:lang=\"it\">Italian</Name>"
                 + "</Names>";

Serializer ser = new Persister();
NameList names = ser.read(NameList.class, xml);

System.out.println(names);
```

Both entries are deserialized correct into `names`. Using another `toString()`-method, i get this:

```
NameList{names=[Name{text=English, attr=en}, Name{text=Italian, attr=it}]}
```

Comment: This is not 100% where i was looking for but i think you can help me too. I have 2 elements with the same name "link" but with another namespace. `<ns1:link>bla</ns1:link>` and `<ns2:link>bla</ns2:link>` when i create 2 elements with `@namespace(prefix="ns1")` and `"ns2"` i got error: _Element 'link' is already used with...._

Comment: @RoDo You can implement a Convert to do this, i think this should work.

Comment: Sorry i got the error: _Duplicate annotation of name_  the error i wrote is when i only instantiate 1 `@Element(name="link")"`  field

Comment: @RoDo I've put my answer to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129210/simple-xml-2-elements-same-name-different-namespace/35254774) -- comments have not enough space.